# column value to an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, row

I have a column which is my third column.

I am stuggling to place the values into an unknown array size when it the button is clicked.

```
 int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; 
            string[] Priority = new string[rowCount];

            if (rowCount > 1) // only sort if bigger than one line
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < rowCount;  i++) 
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = priority[i]; //put data into row thats been added
                }
            }
```

I get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` when I try with more than one row, it is fine if I want to add one value to an array and Im not sure what is wrong with it? Thanks

Comment: As @SushiSlayer stated: `string[] Priority = new string[rowCount];` is declared, but when putting data into a row you assign with `priority[i]`.  Can you confirm if this the case or if it was a typo in your question?  Because changing the declaration to `string[] priority = new string[rowCount]` ran without error for me.  Which then leads me to wonder, how are you adding to the row / what do you mean exactly by "*add one value to an array*"?

Comment: Ive figured it out now, i chose a different route with an arraylist
ArrayList col3Items = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                col3Items.Add(dr.Cells[2].Value);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Modify the value in the first cell of the second row.

this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "new value";

// The previous line is equivalent to the following line.

this.dataGridView1[i, 2].Value = "new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but you instantiate as "Priority"
then you are using 'priority'

prehaps a property named elsewhere?

I agree with the off by one.  the i = 2 is confusing

I'm new, but I thought arrays were always finite in size.

just my thoughts.

[image: Screen Grab from VS]

Comment: By the way, changing Priority to priority still has the index out of range which push me toward the Brendan's answer.  Good luck.

Comment: Interesting.  Changing `Priority` to `priority` actually worked for my test.  On the other hand, changing the `for-loop` condition to match Brendan's then threw the original `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` error.